# Two buttons on one form in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, web

My goal is to have two buttons allocated to one form.  One of the buttons, when clicked, edits the ticket, the second button deletes a ticket.  The form is submitted via AJAX to a controller, which then directs the action appropriately.  What I have tried so far is to send the submit value via AJAX to the controller and then read that there, and call the appropriate model to update the Database, but it is not working.

Here is the relevant code:

The form submit buttons (in the view):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-7">
        <input id="type" style='font-size:18px; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;' name="submit" type="submit" value="Edit Ticket" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9">
        <input id="type" style='font-size:18px; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: -65px;' name="submit" type="submit" value="Delete Ticket" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">
        </div>
</div>
```

The receiving controller:

```
public function editExistingTicket(){
    $this->load->model('tickets');
    $ticketId = $this->input->post('ticketId');

    if ($this->input->post('submit') == 'Edit Ticket') {
        $ticket = array(
                  'ticketId'    => $ticketId,
                  'category'    => $this->input->post('category'),
                  'headline'    => $this->input->post('headline'),
                  'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                  'assigned'    => $this->input->post('assigned'),
                  'open'        => $this->input->post('status'),
                  'priority'    => $this->input->post('priority')
                );
        $edited = $this->tickets->editTicket($ticket);
    } 
    if($this->input->post('submit') == 'Delete Ticket') {
        $this->tickets->deleteTicketById($ticketId);
    }
}
```

The model:

```
public function editTicket($ticket)
{
    $q = $this->db->where('ticketId', $ticket['ticketId']);
    $q = $this->db->update('tickets', $ticket);
    $results = $this->db->affected_rows();
    return $results;
}
```

Am I missing something easy?  Or is the strategy for doing this incorrect?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I think you missed `)` in `if($this->input->post('submit') == 'Delete Ticket' {`

Comment: I did when copying and pasting over, but that wasn't the issue.  It's still not working correctly.

Comment: I'd set the action of the form dynamically with javascript depending on which button was pressed.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but do you mean separate ajax calls depending on the click event of a specific button?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ids of both submit button should be different like

```js
$("#type1").click(function(){
  // Your code
  return false;
});

$("#type2").click(function(){
  // Your code
  return false;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-7">
        <input id="type1" style='font-size:18px; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;' name="submit" type="submit" value="Edit Ticket" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9">
        <input id="type2" style='font-size:18px; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: -65px;' name="submit" type="submit" value="Delete Ticket" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This worked perfectly, although I'm still confused why my original method didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change their names, not their value:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-7">
        <input name="edit" type="submit" value="1" id="type" style='font-size:18px; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;'  class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9">
        <input name="delete" type="submit" value="1" id="type" style='font-size:18px; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: -65px;' class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function editExistingTicket()
{
    $this->load->model('tickets');
    $ticketId = $this->input->post('ticketId');

    if ($this->input->post('edit')) {
        $ticket = array(
            'ticketId'    => $ticketId,
            'category'    => $this->input->post('category'),
            'headline'    => $this->input->post('headline'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'assigned'    => $this->input->post('assigned'),
            'open'        => $this->input->post('status'),
            'priority'    => $this->input->post('priority')
        );
        $edited = $this->tickets->editTicket($ticket);
    } elseif ($this->input->post('delete')) {
        $this->tickets->deleteTicketById($ticketId);
    }
}
```